# Question marks in direct SQL query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, inner-join, rails-activerecord

Disappointed with ActiveRecord which produces inefficient or buggy DELETE queries, I'm looking for an ability to execute direct SQL query in a safe way, free of SQL injection possibility.

I know there is a safe variant of WHERE clause:

```
MyObject.joins(:details)
.where('my_objects.my_value = ? and details.my_id = ?',
params[:value], params[:id])
```

Does the safe variant of `execute` exist? Something like:

```
execute(<<eos
DELETE FROM my_objects
USING details
WHERE
  my_objects.details_id = details.id
  AND my_objects.my_value = ?
  AND details.my_id = ?
eos
, params[:value], params[:id])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't think there is an easier way that can make use of the joins. But there are reusable sanitation helpers for the conditions, at least.

Please see `ActiveRecord::Base#sanitize_sql` ([docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Sanitization/ClassMethods.html#method-i-sanitize_sql)).

```
Model.send(:sanitize_sql, {:foo => "bar"})
```

Answer (score -4):

Why don't u try this:

execute(<<-SQL

DELETE FROM my_objects
  USING details
  WHERE
    my_objects.details_id = details.id
    AND my_objects.my_value = #{params[:value]}
    AND details.my_id = #{params[:id]}

SQL

Comment: This got downvotes because it's very unsafe to take raw data and run it as sql, so don't ever do this. Use parameterized values with `?` or symbol names, like referenced by kristinalim's answer.